# SVG circle move(animateMotion) under the path

Tags: svg, svg-animate, svg-animationelements

I have to write a code that circles should go under some paths with below SVG

```
<g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M718.54,66.06L294.41,490.19c-48.89,48.89-128.09,48.95-176.91,0.13c-48.82-48.82-48.76-128.02,0.13-176.91
            s128.09-48.95,176.91-0.13"/>
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M294.28,313.55l424.13,424.13c48.89,48.89,128.09,48.95,176.91,0.13c48.82-48.82,48.76-128.02-0.13-176.91
            c-48.89-48.89-128.09-48.95-176.91-0.13"/>
    </g>
</g>

<circle r="20" fill="blue">
    <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"
      path="M718.54,66.06L294.41,490.19c-48.89,48.89-128.09,48.95-176.91,0.13c-48.82-48.82-48.76-128.02,0.13-176.91
            s128.09-48.95,176.91-0.13 M294.28,313.55l424.13,424.13c48.89,48.89,128.09,48.95,176.91,0.13c48.82-48.82,48.76-128.02-0.13-176.91
            c-48.89-48.89-128.09-48.95-176.91-0.13" />
```

https://codepen.io/lzwdct/pen/poRYVXZ

Imagine the paths are like driveway, and the circle passes under the path(like bridge) it should not appear under the bridge.

Is there any way to implement it?

Comment: I'd create a small rotated rectangular https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask and apply it to the blue dots to hide them when going under the 'bridge'

Comment: @Ruskin Could you show me a small example please? I tried to use the mask but it does not show up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way SVG mask works is a bit strange. The element it's applied to will only be rendered where the mask is white and where the mask is black (or just not white) it will be hidden. Another strange effect of SVG masks is that if you are animating an element and apply a mask to the element being animated then the mask will move with the element.

To account for the first part is simple, just add a white rect the size of the SVG itself inside the mask and use smaller black shapes to mask. The way to work around the moving mask is to apply the mask not to the element being animated but to a `<g>` tag that wraps the element(s) being animated.

If you want the circles to go 'under' a section and then 'over' that same section however, then you'll need to do some animating inside the mask as well. In this example I'm using `animateTransform` inside the mask's rect child (the black part that does the masking) to shrink it after the circles pass 'under' the bridge, you could just as easily use CSS keyframes though.

I suggest strongly that you also cut down the viewbox since your visual elements are so small compared to the available space, in the example I just estimated but the best way is to re-render your graphics in Illustrator and crop the artboard better to your objects.

Also most of the additional markup produced by Illustrator is not needed if the SVG will be inline in HTML. You can lose pretty much everything except the viewBox as shown in my example since those other attributes are mostly only used when the SVG is rendered as an image, hope this helps.

```css
svg {
  max-width: 500px;
}

.st0,
.st1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #8ea5ae;
  stroke-width: 50;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.st1 {
  stroke-linecap: round
}

.st2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #758992;
  stroke-width: 50;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1015 855">
  <mask id="myMask">
    <!--   Pixels under white are rendered   -->
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1015" height="855" fill="white" />
    <!--   Pixels under black are hidden   -->
    <rect class="moveme" x="315" y="335" height="150" width="150" transform="rotate(45 395 395)">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="scale"
                          keyTimes="0; 0.25999; 0.26; 1"
                          values="1; 1; 0; 0"
                          dur="5s"
                          additive="sum"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </rect>
  </mask>
  
  <path class="st0" d="M718.54,66.06L294.41,490.19c-48.89,48.89-128.09,48.95-176.91,0.13c-48.82-48.82-48.76-128.02,0.13-176.91
            s128.09-48.95,176.91-0.13" />
  <path class="st1" d="M683.19,30.7L258.92,454.97c-29.29,29.29-76.78,29.29-106.07,0c-29.29-29.29-29.29-76.78,0-106.07
            c29.29-29.29,76.78-29.29,106.07,0" />
  <path class="st2" d="M753.9,101.42c0,0-424.26,424.26-424.26,424.26c-68.34,68.34-179.15,68.34-247.49,0s-68.34-179.15,0-247.49
            s179.15-68.34,247.49,0" />
  <path class="st0" d="M294.28,313.55l424.13,424.13c48.89,48.89,128.09,48.95,176.91,0.13c48.82-48.82,48.76-128.02-0.13-176.91 c-48.89-48.89-128.09-48.95-176.91-0.13" />
  <path class="st2" d="M329.63,278.19L753.9,702.46c29.29,29.29,76.78,29.29,106.07,0c29.29-29.29,29.29-76.78,0-106.07 s-76.78-29.29-106.07,0" />
  <path class="st1" d="M258.92,348.9c0,0,424.26,424.26,424.26,424.26c68.34,68.34,179.15,68.34,247.49,0s68.34-179.15,0-247.49 s-179.15-68.34-247.49,0" />
  <!--   Group the circles and apply the mask to the group, not the circles   -->
  <g mask="url(#myMask)">
    <circle r="20" fill="blue">
      <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" path="M718.54,66.06L294.41,490.19c-48.89,48.89-128.09,48.95-176.91,0.13c-48.82-48.82-48.76-128.02,0.13-176.91
            s128.09-48.95,176.91-0.13 M294.28,313.55l424.13,424.13c48.89,48.89,128.09,48.95,176.91,0.13c48.82-48.82,48.76-128.02-0.13-176.91
            c-48.89-48.89-128.09-48.95-176.91-0.13" />
    </circle>
    <circle r="20" fill="blue">
      <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" path="M753.9,101.42c0,0-424.26,424.26-424.26,424.26c-68.34,68.34-179.15,68.34-247.49,0s-68.34-179.15,0-247.49
            s179.15-68.34,247.49,0 M329.63,278.19L753.9,702.46c29.29,29.29,76.78,29.29,106.07,0c29.29-29.29,29.29-76.78,0-106.07
            s-76.78-29.29-106.07,0" />
    </circle>
    <circle r="20" fill="blue">
      <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" path="M683.19,30.7L258.92,454.97c-29.29,29.29-76.78,29.29-106.07,0c-29.29-29.29-29.29-76.78,0-106.07
            c29.29-29.29,76.78-29.29,106.07,0 M258.92,348.9c0,0,424.26,424.26,424.26,424.26c68.34,68.34,179.15,68.34,247.49,0s68.34-179.15,0-247.49
            s-179.15-68.34-247.49,0" />
    </circle>
  </g>
  
  <!-- uncomment the rect below to visualize the animation applied to the mask -->
  <!-- <rect x="315" y="335" height="150" width="150" fill="#f00" opacity=".1" transform="rotate(45 395 395)">
    <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="scale"
                          keyTimes="0; 0.25999; 0.26; 1"
                          values="1; 1; 0; 0"
                          dur="5s"
                          additive="sum"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </rect>-->

</svg>
```

Comment: that's awesome ... does clip-path have the same problem with animation as mask?

Comment: Yes, both of them move with the object being animated if they are applied directly to it. But both can be applied to a parent `<g>` tag to fix the issue. Clip path however works entirely different from mask. Sarah Drasner explains it better than I can https://css-tricks.com/masking-vs-clipping-use/

Comment: @JHeth could you please explain me what values means in the animateTransform?

Comment: Sure, `values` and `keyTimes` work together to provide more control over the timeline of your animation events. The `keyTimes` attribute corresponds to the values inside the `values` attribute. So `keyTimes` sets the timing of each value and `values` provides the sequence of values to apply at each of the specific keyTimes. You can read more about these attributes in the [spec](https://svgwg.org/specs/animations/#ValueAttributes)

Comment: Thanks so much @JHeth. I also posted a new question related to this, do you have any idea to resolve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67513369/svg-circle-color-change-at-certain-point

Comment: That question already has some answers using CSS keyframes which is a perfectly fine approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647521/how-to-animate-the-fill-color-of-svg-with-css