# svg circle color change at certain point

Tags: svg, svg-animate, svg-animationelements

I have a svg that circle is moving around through path. I want the circles' color are changed at some points (ex. mid of the path)

https://codepen.io/lzwdct/pen/poRYVXZ

```
<circle r="20" fill="blue" mask="url(#myMask)">
    <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"
      path="M718.54,66.06L294.41,490.19c-48.89,48.89-128.09,48.95-176.91,0.13c-48.82-48.82-48.76-128.02,0.13-176.91
            s128.09-48.95,176.91-0.13 M294.28,313.55l424.13,424.13c48.89,48.89,128.09,48.95,176.91,0.13c48.82-48.82,48.76-128.02-0.13-176.91
            c-48.89-48.89-128.09-48.95-176.91-0.13" />
</circle>
```

Please guide me how to update the color. The color eventually will be changed multiple times with long paths.

Comment: animate the fill to a different color at whatever time matches the middle of the path

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's anything in SVG that would enable you to do that directly.

But you can check currentTime vs the duration of the animateMotion element and set a color via javascript based on that.

```js
const color = (n) => {
  const R = Math.round((255 * n) / 100);
  const G = Math.round((255 * (100 - n)) / 100);
  const B = 0;
  return `rgb(${R}, ${G}, ${B})`;
};

const circles = document.querySelectorAll("circle");

window.setInterval(() => {
  circles.forEach(circle => {
    const ani = circle.querySelector('animateMotion');
    const duration = ani.getSimpleDuration();
    const currentTime = ani.getCurrentTime() % duration;
    const colorValue = color((currentTime / duration) * 100);
    circle.parentNode.style.fill = colorValue;
  });
}, 500);
```

```css
circle {
  transition: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2549.62 3338.72" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2549.62 3338.72;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#8EA5AE;stroke-width:50;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#8EA5AE;stroke-width:50;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st2{fill:none;stroke:#758992;stroke-width:50;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st3{fill:none;stroke:#758992;stroke-width:50;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st4{fill:none;stroke:#4E5F65;stroke-width:50;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st5{fill:none;stroke:#4E5F65;stroke-width:50;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g>
  <mask id="myMask">
    <!--   Pixels under white are rendered   -->
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="1015" height="855" fill="white" />
    <!--   Pixels under black are hidden   -->
    <rect class="moveme" x="315" y="335" height="150" width="150" transform="rotate(45 395 395)">
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="scale"
                          keyTimes="0; 0.25999; 0.26; 1"
                          values="1; 1; 0; 0"
                          dur="5s"
                          additive="sum"
                          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </rect>
  </mask>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M718.54,66.06L294.41,490.19c-48.89,48.89-128.09,48.95-176.91,0.13c-48.82-48.82-48.76-128.02,0.13-176.91
            s128.09-48.95,176.91-0.13" />
        <path class="st1" d="M683.19,30.7L258.92,454.97c-29.29,29.29-76.78,29.29-106.07,0c-29.29-29.29-29.29-76.78,0-106.07
            c29.29-29.29,76.78-29.29,106.07,0"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M753.9,101.42c0,0-424.26,424.26-424.26,424.26c-68.34,68.34-179.15,68.34-247.49,0s-68.34-179.15,0-247.49
            s179.15-68.34,247.49,0"/>
      
    </g>
    <g>
        <path class="st0" d="M294.28,313.55l424.13,424.13c48.89,48.89,128.09,48.95,176.91,0.13c48.82-48.82,48.76-128.02-0.13-176.91
            c-48.89-48.89-128.09-48.95-176.91-0.13"/>
        <path class="st2" d="M329.63,278.19L753.9,702.46c29.29,29.29,76.78,29.29,106.07,0c29.29-29.29,29.29-76.78,0-106.07
            s-76.78-29.29-106.07,0"/>
        <path class="st1" d="M258.92,348.9c0,0,424.26,424.26,424.26,424.26c68.34,68.34,179.15,68.34,247.49,0s68.34-179.15,0-247.49
            s-179.15-68.34-247.49,0"/>
    </g>
</g>
  <g mask="url(#myMask)">
<circle r="20" mask="url(#myMask)">
    <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"
      path="M718.54,66.06L294.41,490.19c-48.89,48.89-128.09,48.95-176.91,0.13c-48.82-48.82-48.76-128.02,0.13-176.91
            s128.09-48.95,176.91-0.13 M294.28,313.55l424.13,424.13c48.89,48.89,128.09,48.95,176.91,0.13c48.82-48.82,48.76-128.02-0.13-176.91
            c-48.89-48.89-128.09-48.95-176.91-0.13" />
</circle>
<circle r="20">
    <animateMotion dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"
      path="M753.9,101.42c0,0-424.26,424.26-424.26,424.26c-68.34,68.34-179.15,68.34-247.49,0s-68.34-179.15,0-247.49
            s179.15-68.34,247.49,0 M329.63,278.19L753.9,702.46c29.29,29.29,76.78,29.29,106.07,0c29.29-29.29,29.29-76.78,0-106.07 s-76.78-29.29-106.07,0" />
</circle>
<circle r="20">
    <animateMotion id="circle1" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"
      path="M683.19,30.7L258.92,454.97c-29.29,29.29-76.78,29.29-106.07,0c-29.29-29.29-29.29-76.78,0-106.07 c29.29-29.29,76.78-29.29,106.07,0 M258.92,348.9c0,0,424.26,424.26,424.26,424.26c68.34,68.34,179.15,68.34,247.49,0s68.34-179.15,0-247.49 s-179.15-68.34-247.49,0" /></circle></g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak it for your paths, basic concept is to add an `animate` on the element you want to change and use `values` and `keyTimes` (the whole animation is 0 to 1)

As you will notice, you get a color-gradient for free.
If you don't want that, add more `keyTimes` so the color fades occur faster

```html
<svg width="450" height="180">
<path id="PATH" d="M 50 90 H400" stroke="black"/>
  <g>  
    <circle class="circle" r="30" fill="black"></circle>
    <circle class="circle" r=25 fill="red" >
      <animate 
         attributeName="fill"
         attributeType="XML"
         values="red;green;yellow;hotpink;blue"
         keyTimes= "0;0.4;0.6;0.8;1"
         dur="3s"
         repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </circle>
    <animateMotion dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath href="#PATH" />
    </animateMotion>
  </g>       
</svg>
```

svga